# Foreach $_POST - how to increase array pointer to the next element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm looping through the $_POST array (generated form elements) and I need to get the keys and values of the next elements in my foreach loop.

Edit: **The name of the elements for the answers (i.e canbeanynameABC and canbeanynameXYZ) are always unknown.**

Here is an example array:

```
Array ( 
[inputid] => 87 [inputoutputtype] => radio [canbeanynameABC] => radio answer 2 
[inputid] => 88 [inputoutputtype] => radio [canbeanynameXYZ] => radio answer 4 )
```

My code here

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

switch ($key) {

    case "inputid":
            echo "<br/>Value of input_id : " . $value;      
        next($_POST);       
        echo "<br/>Value of inputoutputtype : " . $value;
        next($_POST);       
        echo "<br/>Value of answer : " . $value;        
        break;
}
}
```

I thought that by doing next($_POST), the pointer would now be positioned on the next key/value.

Apparently it doesn't work, i'm getting the following displays:

```
Value of input_id : 87
Value of input_output_type : 87
Value of answer : 87
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: It was suggested that I use arrays to organize my form elements/values. I still can't figure out how to use arrays so that each answer (value) returned from the form, I actually get three values (answer, inputid, inputoutputtype)

Edit: @CBroe I spent the afternoon trying to figure out how to use arrays in $_POST. The form can contain any number of elements, and these elements can be text, radio, select/option, checkbox (can have more than one value returned). Each "value" I get from this form must be associated with an "inputid" and an "inputoutputtype". These form and elements are generated using php, so i'm trying to build a php form handler that will read any numbers of elements and types. The generator is creating unique names for each element so that values don't get overwritten. I'm trying to figure out how to integrate arrays into the generator, but not sure if I'll be able to assign them a row number (i.e [0], [1]..).. maybe I'm just not seeing how arrays would work for my situation.

---

**Update**: Ok, now i'm trying to modify my php form handler to deal with elements that could have any names. I need to be able to read id, type and value (3 different values) from element filled out in the form.

I'm playing around with the form (even though its entirely generated), but not sure what to name my elements

```
<input type='hidden' name='inputradio[inputid]' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='inputradio[inputoutputtype]' value='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='inputradio[output]' value='Radio answer 1'>

<input type='hidden' name='inputradio[inputid]' value='2'>
<input type='hidden' name='inputradio[inputoutputtype]' value='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='inputradio[output]' value='Radio answer 2'>

<input type='hidden' name='inputtext1[inputid]' value='3'>
<input type='hidden' name='inputtext1[inputoutputtype]' value='text'>
<input type='text' name='inputtext1[output]' value='Text answer 1'>

<input type='hidden' name='inputtext2[inputid]' value='4'>
<input type='hidden' name='inputtext2[inputoutputtype]' value='text'>
<input type='text' name='inputtext2[output]' value='Text answer 2'>
```

Should I change the title of this post if the direction changed a but?

Thanks
C

Comment: I don't know PHP, but from what I gathered is that is not how you would use the `next(...)` method. From what I gathered is that the `next(...)` method is used to advance the internal pointer of the array (right? or something similar?) Anywho, `$key` and `$value` are what you're working with, not the internal pointer. So I'd rewrite the switch to handle all three cases and then ignore the fourth/fifth (if that's what you've intended) and see if that works. It just seems that since you are referencing the array's internal pointer you aren't doing much by calling `$key` and `$value`. Make sense?

Comment: Your approach is flawed from the beginning. Instead of trying to access the next element and the element after that within the foreach loop, you should name your form elements in a way that you get a _usable data structure_ in the first place. Hint: You can use `[` and `]` in form element names to create arrays in $_POST, and you can even specify the desired index, f.e. `name="foo[0][id]`, `name="foo[0][outputtype]`, etc.

Comment: I think this is more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two properties to an entry in $_POST, the key and the value. I don't know where you got your example array, but it doesn't work like that. So if I had a radio button group with all sharing the same name, I would get the name->value pair.

If I created the following form and I submitted it with value a selected in the radio button group:

```
<form method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="textbox" value="test"><br/>
    a.<input type="radio" name="rd" value="a"><br/>
    b.<input type="radio" name="rd" value="b"><br/>
    c.<input type="radio" name="rd" value="c"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

my $_POST would contain the following values:

```
Array
(
    [textbox] => test
    [rd] => a
)
```

if I tried to step through my array, I would do so as follows:

```
for ($_POST as $key->$value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Which would give me the following output:

```
textbox = test
rd = a
```

Can you tell me what problem you are trying to solve, since it seems you are approaching this from the point of view of some other language or framework, or possibly you are looking to work with some other array in PHP that is not $_POST?

Comment: Thanks Keith, I understand that. For each of the two values from your example, I would like to pass/associate an inputid (id from db) and inputoutputtype (text,radio, etc.). The thing is that the initial form is generated by the user, so it can contain many input field of many types. I'm trying to build a php handler that would read through $_POST and find all the different values (associated with inputid and inputoutputtype) even if I don't know the names of the input elements (names are generated), then write the values (with their types) on the database (pointing to the right input id).

Comment: I can see one of two ways to handle it. One, include a hidden field for every actual field, but prepend something to the name so it could be filtered out (alternatively, one hidden field with a JSON or other list of the same data could be used for all the form data). Secondly, you could read and parse the page that contains the form and check for the form and elements. Either of these two methods would allow you to create a multidimensional list of all fields, their type, their id and value.

Comment: Thanks @keith-rockhold, I tried to understand and find examples, but this goes beyond my knowledge of php. I'm not even sure what to look for. I've updated my question up there. I'm trying to group 3 values into one (array maybe?)  and get my form handler to understand whats going on, even if the names are unknown to the handler.

Comment: Why not just use the name field for all that data, splitting it with _ or other character. So your <input type='text' name='inputtext2[output]' value='Text answer 2'> would end up being <input type='text' name='input_text_id_type' value='Text answer 2'>? Then you can simply step through the $_POST array, explode the name field to get all the different array values you require.